# How to correctly read useragent with special chars

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, user-agent

I have recently had some visitors with the following useragent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.6; es-co; XT320 Build/GRK39F) 
AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Versión/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

I insert these in a mysql table on a column that is utf8_general_ci . My PHP site is also served as UTF-8.
Unfortunately, I have gotten some errors from these visitors as follows:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF3n/4.0...' for column 'useragent' at row 1 [1366]
```

Hence it is the ó that is causing the problem.
In my quest to resolve this, I changed the useragent of my firefox browser to this as well (with UA switcher plugin), but this gets inserted perfectly into my database.

So, my question: how is it possible that in some cases it's apparently not working? And how could this be resolved?
I could of course just replace ó with o, but I would think this will not be the last special char I'll be encountering in the future...

Comment: How are you inserting the data into the database? Can you post an example?

Comment: I'm simply building the query as a string, and setting the value to `mysqli_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])`

Answer (score 1):

Your database likely expects UTF-8 encoded data to be sent, but the user agent is inexplicably encoded in Latin-1 or some other specialized encoding. This *should* not be, since HTTP headers should not use non-ASCII characters, since there's no mechanism to specify how HTTP headers are encoded, wherefore it's impossible to know what encoding one is dealing with.

You have found a non-conforming user agent. You should inspect all received strings whether they fit your expected encoding; e.g. using `mb_check_encoding($str, 'UTF-8')`. If the string is not in the expected encoding, all bets are off and you can do whatever you feel is right. Discard the string, try to guesstimate its encoding and convert it, replace invalid bytes or whatever else you feel like.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that The string is generated with the overridden codepage from the user. You can try

```
$Str =  mb_convert_encoding ( string , "auto", "UTF-8")
```

Before sending it to the DB

Comment: Should it not be `mb_convert_encoding(string, "UTF-8", "auto")` then?